# Can't scroll content of ScrollableTabView with ScrollView

Tags: react-native

I created pages for tabs and  put the view inside the ScrollView but it doesnt scroll down. I tried to give a flex:1 and flexGrow:1, but didnt change anything at alll. All i want is text part is able to scroll down freely. Is there anything that im missing? or any about how can i apporach to that issue?

I removed seme unnecessary stuff like  text styles etc. so here's the script:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Animated, ScrollView, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import ScrollableTabView from 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view';
import TabBar from 'react-native-underline-tabbar';
import { RFPercentage } from "react-native-responsive-fontsize";
import * as Font from "expo-font";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#027EB3',
    },

    textStyle: {
        marginHorizontal:"5%",
        color: "white",
        marginVertical: "5%",
        fontFamily: "Gotham-Book"
        
    },
    imageStyle: {
        width: "100%",
        height:"65%"
    },
    ScrollViewStyle: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    konukTextStyle: {
        fontFamily: "Gotham-Book",
        color: "white",
        fontSize: RFPercentage(3.5)
    },
    konukTextViewStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        marginLeft:"5%"
    }
});

const Page = ({ label, text = '' }) => (
    <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
            {text}
        </Text>
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
);


const Tab = ({ tab, page, isTabActive, onPressHandler, onTabLayout, styles }) => {
    const { label, icon } = tab;
    const style = {
        marginHorizontal: 10,
        paddingVertical: 5,
    };
    const containerStyle = {
        paddingVertical: 5,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        backgroundColor: styles.backgroundColor,
        opacity: styles.opacity,
        transform: [{ scale: styles.opacity }],
    };
    const textStyle = {
        color: styles.textColor,
        fontFamily: "Gotham-Book",
    };
    const iconStyle = {
        tintColor: styles.textColor,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        width: 22,
        height: 22,
        marginLeft: 10,
    };
    const seperator = {
        width: 1.1,
        backgroundColor: '#027EB3',
        height: '100%',
    };
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={style} onPress={onPressHandler} onLayout={onTabLayout} key={page}>
            <Animated.View style={containerStyle}>
                <Animated.Text style={textStyle}>{label}</Animated.Text>
                <Animated.Image style={iconStyle} source={icon} />
                <View style={seperator} />
            </Animated.View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};

class UnderlineTabBarExample extends Component {
    _scrollX = new Animated.Value(0);
    interpolators = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => i).map(idx => ({
        scale: this._scrollX.interpolate({
            inputRange: [idx - 1, idx, idx + 1],
            outputRange: [1, 1.2, 1],
            extrapolate: 'clamp',
        }),
        opacity: this._scrollX.interpolate({
            inputRange: [idx - 1, idx, idx + 1],
            outputRange: [0.9, 1, 0.9],
            extrapolate: 'clamp',
        }),
        textColor: this._scrollX.interpolate({
            inputRange: [idx - 1, idx, idx + 1],
            outputRange: ['#027EB3', '#027EB3', '#027EB3'],
        }),
        backgroundColor: this._scrollX.interpolate({
            inputRange: [idx - 1, idx, idx + 1],
            outputRange: ['#CFF3FF', '#CFF3FF', '#CFF3FF'],
            extrapolate: 'clamp',
        }),
    }));


    render() {
        if (!this.state.fontLoaded) { return null; }
        return (
            <View style={[styles.container]}>
                <ImageBackground
                    source={require("../../assets/GuestImage.png")}
                    resizeMode="contain"
                    style={styles.imageStyle}

                    imageStyle={{ height: "118%", width:"100%" }}
                >
                    <View style={styles.konukTextViewStyle}>
                        <Text style={styles.konukTextStyle}>SERDAR</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.konukTextStyle} >YILDIRIM, KONUK</Text>
                    </View>
                </ImageBackground>
            <View>
                    <ScrollableTabView
                        renderTabBar={() => (
                            <TabBar
                                underlineColor="#027EB3"
                                tabBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#CFF3FF", borderTopColor: '#d2d2d2', borderTopWidth: 1 }}
                                renderTab={(tab, page, isTabActive, onPressHandler, onTabLayout) => (
                                    <Tab
                                        key={page}
                                        tab={tab}
                                        page={page}
                                        isTabActive={isTabActive}
                                        onPressHandler={onPressHandler}
                                        onTabLayout={onTabLayout}
                                        styles={this.interpolators[page]}
                                    />
                                )}
                            />
                        )}
                        onScroll={(x) => this._scrollX.setValue(x)}
                    >
                        <Page tabLabel={{ label: "PORTRAIT" }} text={`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. \n Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons ectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\n Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis`} />
                        <Page tabLabel={{ label: "MYCITY" }} text={`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. \n Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons ectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\n Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis`} />
                        <Page tabLabel={{ label: "CHECKING IN" }} text={`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. \n Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons ectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\n Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis`} />
                       
                            </ScrollableTabView>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default UnderlineTabBarExample;
```

i also tried this way way but still can't scroll down even the borders are goes down from the screen:

```js
<ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, borderWidth: 2, borderColor:"red" }} tabLabel={{ label: "PORTRAIT" }}>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.textStyle}> {`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. \n Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons ectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\n Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis`} </Text>
   </View>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: here as we can see borders goes down from the screen]

Answer (score 0):

Problem Fixed. I just forget to give  flex to View of .

```
   <View style={{flex:1}}>
                    <ScrollableTabView

                        renderTabBar={() => (
                            <TabBar
                                underlineColor="#027EB3"
                                 {...}
```